# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_ids' in 'field list'

Tags: php, magento

problem in Magento ver. 1.3.2.4

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_ids' in 'field list'

can anyone help?

i go to Add products, Edit product but i get that error when trying to save.

Answer (score 1):

Please install your Magento once again, because at the time of installation, the column "category_ids" were not properly created in this table mainly. This problem sometimes happens with Magento, if not everything is okay (like the Internet Speed & Hosting Server's Bandwidth & others).

You may also find some other problems in this Magento installation, because normally if one problem with products arises, some more problems creep up soon enough.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1. Reinstall of Magento/reimport of the database has solved this issue for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is an error in your SQL query.  It's looking for the column named 'category_ids' in the table it's querying but that column doesn't exist.